# Regex table get domain name from email in Google Tag Manager (GTM)

Tags: regex, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

Does anyone know how to extract a domain name from an email address using a Regex table in Google Tag Manager? For example, I would need the return value 'google' in this email address first.name@google.com

The data layer variable returns a standard email address, but it seems like I can't change it to a company value. Thank you in advance for your help.

The regex I use:

```js
(?<=@)[^.]+(?=\.)
```

against `first.name@google.com` matches `google`.

[Regex101 match information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5ZKg.png) https://regex101.com/r/vE8rP9/1

[Google Tag Manager Regex Lookup Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NfQq.png)

Comment: Did you try to remove the lookbehind and just use `@([^.]+)`?

Comment: Could you just do:  @".*@(.*)\.com

Comment: Can you share a link to regex101 (see `Save` link on the top left) instead of posting a screenshot of it? This way we can help directly and way faster.

Comment: This is the regex https://regex101.com/r/vE8rP9/1. The regex you are providing does not seem to work in GTM LUT.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```js
@([^.]+)\.
```

And if necessary, set the `Output` to `$1`. That is, instead of lookarounds, the `(?<=@)` lookbehind and `(?=\.)` lookahead, you can convert these non-consuming patterns into consuming ones, and wrap the part of the pattern you are interested in with capturing parentheses.

*Details*:

- `@` - a `@` char
- `([^.]+)` - Group 1: one or more chars other than `.`
- `\.` - a `.` char.

Answer (score -2):

This addresses your question:
[image]
Here is the regex (https://regex101.com/r/JzbMJJ/1):

```
@(.*)\.
```

Use $1 for output. Uncheck the full matches only.

I would suggest not using LUT for it. A CJS variable would look much more organic there.

Comment: The advantage of a lookup table over a custom javascript variable is that custom javascript requires eval, so it will not work with a sensible CSP in place (probably not a problem for the OP, but something to keep in mind).

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reply. Currently, the suggested answer does not provide a solution, unfortunately.